# Subtle error in probability of intersection

Tags: probability

Consider the sets $A, B, \text{and}~ C$.

[image]

Assume that $P(A \cup B)$ has already been computed by inclusion-exclusion and $P(A \cup B) = X$. We now want to find $P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C)$.

My derivation is as follows:

By DeMorgan we have,
$$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C)^c = P(A \cup B \cup C^c)$$

Now I know it's not listed as a law of absorption, but just by inspection of the diagram, isn't it the case that $$P(A \cup B \cup C^c) = P(A \cup B)$$
since $C^c$ is everything in $A$ and $B$ not also in C, which is just being unioned with $A \cup B$ anyway?

If that's the case, then $$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C) = 1 - P(A \cup B) = 1 - X$$.

But that is incorrect based on the answer to the specific question I am working on.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: In a general Venn diagram of three sets, it is always considered possible that the union of the three sets is not the entire universe. I don’t see any indication in this problem that we should assume otherwise. Instead, it looks like something is missing from the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

$A^c\cap B^c\cap C=(A\cup B\cup C)\setminus (A\cup B)$, You can now use the fact that $A\cup B\subset A\cup B\cup C$.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I know it's not listed as a law of absorption, but just by inspection of the diagram, isn't it the case that
> $P (A \cup B \cup C^c) = P (A \cup B)$

This is not true. There could be points in $C^c$ that are not included in $A \cup B$, in which case $A \cup B$ would be strictly contained in $A \cup B \cup C^c$.

Comment: There are no other sets besides $A, B, C$. If an element is not in $C$, where could it be other than $A$ or $B$?

Comment: If the entire space is $A \cup B \cup C$, then it would indeed be the case that $A^c \cap B^c \cap C = (A \cup B)^c$. This isn't hard to see.

Comment: I know, which is why I alluded to as much. Based on the description of the problem, it it is. But for the sake of argument, let's suppose that $(A \cup B \cup C)$ isn't the entire space. Now suppose we're given $P(A), P(B), P(C), P(A \cap B), P(A \cap C), P(B \cap C), \text{and}~ P(A \cap B \cap C)$. Also, assume we have previously computed $P(A \cup B)$. What is the correct derivation to find $P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C)$?

Comment: In that case, you can use $A^c \cap B^c \cap C = (A \cup B)^c \cap C = C - [(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)]$. Using PIE, we have that $P((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)) = P (A \cap C) + P (B \cap C) - P (A \cap B \cap C)$, so that the desired probability is $(P (C) + P (A \cap B \cap C)) - (P (A \cap C) + P (B \cap C))$.

Comment: Thanks! Which laws of set theory took you from $(A∪B)^c \cap C$
 to $C - [(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C))]$ exactly?

Comment: Let $X$ be the entire space. We have $(A \cup B)^c \cap C = (X - (A \cup B)) \cap C = (X \cap C) - (A \cup B) \cap C = C - [(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)]$.